# react-google-maps use without re-render

Tags: reactjs, recompose, react-google-maps

I Have 1 task and 1 problem.
I use [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/) .
My task is: add markers by the event. 
My problem - after every adding point position marker re-render component GoogleMap. And map has flicker effect if i use statefull component or HOC.
I've tried use recompose. Good library. But a marker is added to the state but the marker is not added to the map.
Give some advice for resolve this problem.

Comment: A marker should be an independent component and it shouldn't trigger re-rendering on a map. Please show your code because it's hard to guess what you are doing wrong without it.

Comment: Did you figure it out?